# How to hide an application icon in Android emulator?

Tags: android

I have an application which launch automatically after the booting finished,but the application icon is displayed in the android emulator.Now i want to hide that icon from the user.So that the user cannot know from the application is lanuch and they cannot launch that application manually.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"In your AndroidManifest.xml file you probably have a line that says

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

This line tells ANdroid that it "Should be displayed in the top-level launcher." Remove that line and you should be set.