# Cant hide application icon from the Android Menu?

Tags: android

I have also landed in a situation where I want to start Install of a third party app (lets say app Y) from my app (X) and I do not want application Y icon to get created on android main menu.

I have tried code below but still there is a icon of app Y that is getting created in main menu after App Y gets installed successfully. Just please remember that I can not change manifest of App Y as it is a third party app.

I have also tried suggestions on following link but they have not resolved my problem:

[How to hide application icon from the Android Desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184300/how-to-hide-application-icon-from-the-android-desktop/6780721#6780721)
++++++++++

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/MyApps/App Y.apk");

Intent intent = new Intent();
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.removeCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(uri.toString()),
"application/vnd.android.package-archive");

startActivity(intent);
```

++++++++++

Please let me know your suggestions/inputs on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this is to remove the `IntentFilter` defined in the package's AndroidManifest.xml file: there is no way as a third party installer to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases the answer will be no you can't....

It depends of what kind of application "App Y" is. For e.g. if App Y is a library it is included in your app. There are some sample app's available on the Android site like; "Soft Keyboard"

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html

Those are actually "services" which are not installed as applications. If App Y is a "normal" application it will be installed on it's own as this is Android's behaviour.

Kind regards and good luck on further development.

Answer (score 0):

You're just modifying your intent. I don't think it's possible to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish. Why not let the user launch the other app themselves?

Comment: @Ronnie, thanks all for your support. so it seems that this is not possible in android. So, to think more on this is there some other way I can restrict the users to open App Y from Main Menu.

Comment: in short, no. Is there any chance you're trying to thinly wrap a different application that you don't want others to know you're wrapping? Again, I would love to hear why you're trying to prevent such a thing so aggressively...

Comment: the reason behind to do this, is my whole app idea so  cant really share this right now. in future once i am done with this i will definitely let you know. again thankx for your help and support...

Answer (score 0):

```
// Hide Application Icon 

try{
    PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


// UnHide Application Icon


PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("com.example.removeicon","com.example.removeicon.LauncherActivity");
                    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName , PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can bluff just create an image with 0 opacity and smallest possible size then user will not be able to see the application.