# Disable Application Icon

Tags: android

Is there any sample to hide android's native application icon from launching without uninstalling the application ie, enable or disable app icon .

I have searched many samples with solution to use 
"PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting" , but it works only for current application component.

Comment: dude i found something go to this link http://androidforums.com/developer-101/210047-hide-application-android-application-list.html here is the way to remove icon .

Comment: Have you checked this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184300/how-to-hide-application-icon-from-the-android-desktop/6780721#6780721

Comment: Ya i referred the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496955/disable-application-icon, but nothing helps me

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it is not possible to hide the installed application's icon. Anything which not an Android OS is displayed in the menu with icon to open & access. you can not hide it.

Probably to make it hide, you need to add it into the OS