# How to hide an app and give it the right to be access from another app?

Tags: android, android-intent

I hope anyone can help me or give me a clear solution,

I have an app that I don't want to be opened directly from the user, so I need to hide its icon.

and in the other hand, I want to access this application from another app (App2), so I wrote this code in the function of onClick of a  certain button of App2:

```
 Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(package name of the first app );

    startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Before hiding the App1 , everything was working perfectly No errors but after hiding it using the following code, it crashes:

```
 PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();  
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this,FingerActivity.class);     
    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

and the following error appear in Android Studio:

> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   cmp=com.neurotec.samples.multibiometric/.fingers.FingerActivity }
>   Error type 3 Error: Activity class
>   {com.neurotec.samples.multibiometric/com.neurotec.samples.multibiometric.fingers.FingerActivity}
>   does not exist.

any idea?

Comment: This may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184300/how-to-hide-application-icon-from-the-android-desktop

Answer (score 0):

> any idea?

You disabled the component. You cannot start the component from any other app.

> I have an app that I don't want to be opened directly from the user, so I need to hide its icon.

The simplest way for it to not have an icon is for you to not give it an icon. Change your `<intent-filter>` for that activity to be something custom for you, rather than having it have the `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` values that causes home screens to put an icon for it in the launcher.

Comment: I tried to change <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> to OPENABLE and it didnt work

Comment: @RimaHajou: Probably you did not include that category in the `Intent` that you used to try to launch the activity. `DEFAULT` would be a better choice than `OPENABLE`. Beyond that, `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` will not work; construct your `Intent` directly, as you know the values that should go in there, based on your `<intent-filter>`.